# How to get non-zero exit status with lintr::lint() in order to fail a build

Tags: r, build, lintr

I am trying to help our group of developers obtain similar code styles by using the `lintr` package when writing R code. To automate this step, I want our builds to fail if there are any mistakes (bad styles) in the code. We are using Jenkins for our build pipeline if that matters.

I know that we could use the `expect_lint_free` function, but we are not making packages, only script files. The output from the `lint` function looks fine, but the build passes even when the linter returns improvement proposals. How do I get a non-zero exit status that will make the Jenkins build fail?

The (simplified) code run on the command line

```
Rscript -e "lintr::lint('my_script.R')"
```

returns no error but lots of proposals.

Note: I am not interested in "Create an R package" solutions at the moment.

Comment: Why don't you write a wrapper function around `lint` that catches those improvement proposals and returns non-zero in that case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `lintr::lint()` function returns results in a list with class `"lints"`.  You have issues if its length is greater than zero, so you can do

```
Rscript -e "quit(save = 'no', status = length(lintr::lint('my_script.R')))"
```

Answer (score 5):

While the solution by @user2554330 works and exits with a non-zero exit code, it suppresses the output from `lintr`. However, you'd generally like to see where it fails when it does.
You can achieve this like so:

```sh
Rscript -e "errors <- lintr::lint('my_script.R'); print(errors); quit(save = 'no', status = length(errors))"
```

Or for all `.r` files:

```sh
Rscript -e "errors <- lintr::lint_dir(); print(errors); quit(save = 'no', status = length(errors))"
```

Answer (score 1):

Kind of an old question but `lintr` has a built-in solution to throw non-zero exit status if there are lints returned. I found this in the package vignette (`vignette("lintr")`): `error_on_lint`. This configuration is `FALSE` by default. If you are using the default configuration approach of using a `.lintr` file (see: `lintr::use_lintr()`) you can simply add a line like this:
`error_on_lint: TRUE`

Once you have setup `.lintr` with `error_on_lint: TRUE` configuration, then (for example) running:

```r
> Rscript -e "lintr::lint_dir()"
R\hello.R:3:44: style: [trailing_whitespace_linter] Trailing whitespace is superfluous.
# This is an example function named 'hello'
                                           ^
> echo $?
31
```

I found this is only useful for non-interactive work (like your Jenkins build step). Otherwise, it will restart your R session if there are lints, and it won't even say what they were.

One last thought: you mentioned running this in a Jenkins build step. You could use a git hook like pre-commit to lint your code *before* making commits. Could prevent messy commits cleaning up code, as well as time, if the prior build steps are slow.